# How can I convert an implied decimal point to a real decimal point in java?

Tags: java, decimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to take a string and convert into a currency. For example I would like to take the string 12579500 and convert it to $125,795.00. I am trying to use DecimalFormat("$#,###.00), to convert the string after I turn it into a double, but what I'm winding up with is $12,579,500.00.

How do I set the last 2 numbers at the end of the string to be decimal points?

Here is my code so far.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
double ticketPriceNum = Double.parseDouble(ticketPrice);
System.out.print(df.format(ticketPriceNum));
```

Comment: Divide the `double` value by 100 before formatting.

Comment: have you tried just dividing the `ticketPriceNum` by `100`?

Comment: that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###,##.00");
    //if last two digits of ticketprice should be decimal points
    double ticketPriceNum = Double.parseDouble(ticketPrice/100);

    System.out.println(df.format(ticketPriceNum  ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure that your string is reduced by 2 characters

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
    double ticketPriceNum = Double.parseDouble(ticketPrice.substring(0, ticketPrice.length()- 2));
    System.out.print(df.format(ticketPriceNum));
```